# I cant configure my grunt file for haml

Tags: html, ruby, gruntjs, haml, config

dose any one know how I can configure my grunt file for haml?

I have this now:

```
haml: {
    dist: {
    files: {
        'index.html': 'index.haml'
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried `

```
haml: {
dist: {
    files: {
        ['index.html']: 'index.haml'
        }
    }
}
```

both along with

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-haml');
```

I've been able to get compass running but not haml. I tried the config.rb file as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine you did, but are you registering the task at the end of your Gruntfile.js file? Also, what error messages (if any) are you getting when you run 'grunt haml -v' from the command line?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
     haml: {
      dist: {
        files: { 
          'index.html':'index.haml'
        }
      }
     });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-haml');

  grunt.registerTask('default','['haml']);
```

^^^^ this last bit here, is it in your Gruntfile? You should have something similar for Compass to run.

This package always gives me some grief when I install it, for whatever reason.